# Can my phone go silent whenever I'm asleep?

Tags: iphone

Is there a setting, app, or combination of apps that can turn my phone silent whenever I'm asleep without me needing to schedule or toggle anything?

So if I'm up late or early I still hear a text arrive, but if I nap midday it's silent, without me needing to remember to turn some settings on or off? Maybe some sleep app can do this? Or maybe IFTTT, tasker, workflow, or some other, can deduce whether I'm asleep, from Fitbit, or some other sleep app?

My phone is a tad dated (iPhone 8), so a solution that doesn't suck lots of battery would be preferable.

Comment: Have you got an Apple Watch? Your iPhone cannot detect if you're sleeping, but it can interact with your Apple Watch that can. But this won't work for you I think since you don't want to set anything (schedule, etc.). Your question does not leave much wiggle room for answer. You might want to reduce the amount of needed parameters - there's almost no way of doing what you want without setting a shortcut, automation or schedule.

Comment: you say "almost no way"...well if you have a way, submit an answer!

Answer (score -1):

If you are running iOS 15 or later (iPhone 8 can run iOS 16), there is a “Do not Disturb” feature called *Focus*, that includes a “sleep” setting that will silence all notifications during this period

You can set this manually (Control Center → Tap Focus) or if you’ve set up a sleep schedule, it will do this automatically.

See [Use Focus on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608) for full details.

Comment: *"without me needing to schedule or toggle anything"* - Your answer is great but it does not really answer the question. Your answer provides him with infos on setting a schedule or toggling Focus.